# Try to make an http api request through angular frontend

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a rest API container in java/spring and containerize to a docker service.
The frontend is written in angular and is served through NGINX server.
Unfortunately the call to http://service-rest:8080/api/call fails.
Any ideas on this

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  service-frontend;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
           root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
           index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /api {
           proxy_pass http://service-rest:8080;
        } 
    }
}
```

Backend controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin
public class EntityController {

    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository entityRepository;

    @GetMapping("/entities")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<NumberArray>> getEntities() {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(entityRepository.findAll(Pageable.unpaged()));
    }

    @PostMapping("/entities")
    public ResponseEntity<Entity> createEntity(@Valid @RequestBody Entity entity) throws JsonProcessingException {

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(entityRepository.save(entity));
    }

}
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "2"
services:
  service-db:
    image: postgres:9.4.5
    container_name: service-db
    hostname: service-db
    network_mode: bridge
    volumes:
      - service-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    environment:
         - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
         - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
         - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  service-server:
    build: serviceserver/.
    container_name: service-server
    hostname: service-server
    network_mode: bridge
    expose:
      - 1234
    ports:
      - 1234:1234
    restart: unless-stopped
  service-rest:
    build: servicerest/.
    container_name: service-rest
    hostname: service-rest

    network_mode: bridge

    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - service-db
    links:
      - service-db
      - service-server
  service-frontend:
    build: servicefrontend/.
    container_name: service-frontend
    hostname: service-frontend
    network_mode: bridge

    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    depends_on:
      - service-rest
    links:
      - service-rest



volumes:
    service-db-data:
```

Browser message
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://service-rest:8080/api/call. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): sf: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http://service-rest:8080/api/call","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://service-rest:8080/api/numberarrays: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}"

Comment: Can you please post the error details... ? What did you get on the browser? or postman... or curl... or whatever tool you're using for testing the service..

Comment: Just seeing the nginx config doesn't help us much. Could you please share your front-end (and maybe back-end) code as well as the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Calling the precise http request like

```
  client.get("http//service-rest:8080/api/call")
```

is wrong

the right way is to call

```
   client.get("/api/call")
```